# What power was Luke using at the end of The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, the-last-jedi, luke-skywalker

When Luke used the Force in his

> final move to distract the First Order on Crait,

what power specifically was he utilizing? Force projection? Force illusion? Mind-trick?

The simple answer is to assume Luke was projecting himself onto the planet but is it possible he was manipulating everyone's mind into seeing an illusion instead? I've never read where Force users could project themselves at such a great distance but it's not unheard of for a Jedi or Sith to effect the minds of other beings from across the galaxy.

Comment: It appears to have been an entirely new power invented for the film

Comment: Force telepresence?

Comment: The same power Snoke was using for the Rey and Kylo

Comment: @Edlothiad, no it is not. That was more of a mind link.

Comment: @Valorum It's not wholly unprecedented. While slightly different, Yoda appears in physical form through the force to Ezra and Ahsoka in the Rebels series, without being physically present.